# Python 3: Opening multiple .csv files

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I want to open multiple csv files (with same data types/columns), save the data into one variable do some stuff to data and save it into one csv file. While I can easily open one file, I can't seem to find a way to open multiple files.  Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from collections import Counter

files = ['11.csv', '12.csv', '13.csv', '14.csv', '15.csv']

with open(files) as csvfile:
    info = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    info_types = []
    records = 0
    for row in info:
        records = row[2]
        call_types.append(records)
stats = Counter(call_types).most_common()
print(stats)

results = stats
resultFile = open("Totals.csv",'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
for output in results:
    wr.writerow(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, simultaneouly less bug prone and **efficient** try the following.

```
# required imports

files = ['11.csv', '12.csv', '13.csv', '14.csv', '15.csv']

with open("outfile","wt") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as csvfile:
            info = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            info_types = []
            records = 0
            for row in info:
                # process row but don't store it
                # in any list if you
                # don't have to(that will defeat the purpose)
                # say you get processed_row
                writer.writerow(processed_row)
```

Comment: Thanks much. It worked like a dream! Now I have to figure out how to skip the headers for each file following the first.

Comment: @Chuck Just add `header = next(info)` before `for row in info:`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this within a loop. Since you are already appending the data as you are reading from the file.

```
for f in files:
    with open(f) as csvfile:
        ...
```